# Error using Homebrew to install go projects

Tags: macos, go, homebrew

Now I try to install any `go` project with `brew` but I get the same error

```
➜ brew install etcd
==> Installing etcd dependency: go
==> Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.4.src.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/go-1.4.tar.gz
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to bother you. It works after a few minutes. Maybe it's the problem of go 1.4 but finally it works.

```
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> ./make.bash --no-clean
==> Caveats
As of go 1.2, a valid GOPATH is required to use the `go get` command:
  http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

`go vet` and `go doc` are now part of the go.tools sub repo:
  http://golang.org/doc/go1.2#go_tools_godoc

To get `go vet` and `go doc` run:
  go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet
  go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc

You may wish to add the GOROOT-based install location to your PATH:
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4: 7695 files, 1.5G, built in 9.5 minutes
==> Installing etcd
==> Downloading https://github.com/coreos/etcd/archive/v0.4.6.tar.gz
```